# Недоступен из-за уровня защиты

Tags: c#

Пытаюсь подключить через библиотеку, но пишет, что GroupRepository недоступен из-за уровня защиты.

```
 namespace CourseWork
 {
   class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var groups = new Library.GroupRepository.;
        var subjects = new SubjectRepository();
        var audiences = new RoomsRepository();
        var planner = new PlanRepository();
        groups.Adding(new Group() { ID = 1, Flow = "ИС", GroupNum = 91 });
        groups.Adding(new Group() { ID = 2, Flow = "ИС", GroupNum = 92 });
        groups.Adding(new Group() { ID = 3, Flow = "ИС", GroupNum = 93 });

        subjects.Adding(new Subject() { ID = 1, Lesson = "Physics", Teacher = "Fedotov V.V.", Type = "lecture", Hours = 5 });
        subjects.Adding(new Subject() { ID = 2, Lesson = "Physics", Teacher = "Marchenko I.P.", Type = "practice", Hours = 5 });
        subjects.Adding(new Subject() { ID = 3, Lesson = "Physics", Teacher = "Ignatenko О.М", Type = "practice", Hours = 8 });
        subjects.Adding(new Subject() { ID = 4, Lesson = "Physics", Teacher = "Liakhovetskiy O.D.", Type = "practice", Hours = 8 });
        subjects.Adding(new Subject() { ID = 5, Lesson = "Math", Teacher = "Zhuk V.A.", Type = "lecture", Hours = 9 });
        subjects.Adding(new Subject() { ID = 6, Lesson = "Math", Teacher = "Orel K.M.", Type = "lecture", Hours = 5 });
        subjects.Adding(new Subject() { ID = 7, Lesson = "Math", Teacher = "Pelekhata O.B.", Type = "practice", Hours = 5 });
        subjects.Adding(new Subject() { ID = 8, Lesson = "Programming", Teacher = "Muha I.P.", Type = "lecture", Hours = 5 });
        subjects.Adding(new Subject() { ID = 9, Lesson = "Programming", Teacher = "Brodin O.M.", Type = "practice", Hours = 5 });
        subjects.Adding(new Subject() { ID = 10, Lesson = "OOS", Teacher = "Yarovoy V.M.", Type = "lecture", Hours = 2 });
        subjects.Adding(new Subject() { ID = 11, Lesson = "OOS", Teacher = "Khramchenlo N.I.", Type = "practice", Hours = 1 });
        subjects.Adding(new Subject() { ID = 12, Lesson = "English", Teacher = "Shevchenko I.O.", Type = "practice", Hours = 5 });
        subjects.Adding(new Subject() { ID = 13, Lesson = "English", Teacher = "Borysova M.Y.", Type = "practice", Hours = 5 });
        subjects.Adding(new Subject() { ID = 14, Lesson = "History", Teacher = "Kostyleva O.K.", Type = "lecture", Hours = 1 });
        subjects.Adding(new Subject() { ID = 15, Lesson = "History", Teacher = "Buzan I.P.", Type = "practice", Hours = 5 });

        audiences.Adding(new Room() { ID = 1, Number = 102, Lesson = "Physics", Type = "lecture" });
        audiences.Adding(new Room() { ID = 2, Number = 107, Lesson = "Programming", Type = "lecture" });
        audiences.Adding(new Room() { ID = 3, Number = 112, Lesson = "OOS", Type = "practice" });
        audiences.Adding(new Room() { ID = 4, Number = 217, Lesson = "Physics", Type = "practice" });
        audiences.Adding(new Room() { ID = 5, Number = 102, Lesson = "Math", Type = "lecture" });
        audiences.Adding(new Room() { ID = 6, Number = 118, Lesson = "Math", Type = "practice" });
        audiences.Adding(new Room() { ID = 7, Number = 133, Lesson = "OOS", Type = "lecture" });
        audiences.Adding(new Room() { ID = 8, Number = 115, Lesson = "Physics", Type = "practice" });
        audiences.Adding(new Room() { ID = 9, Number = 36, Lesson = "Programming", Type = "practice" });
        audiences.Adding(new Room() { ID = 10, Number = 123, Lesson = "English", Type = "practice" });
        audiences.Adding(new Room() { ID = 11, Number = 223, Lesson = "History", Type = "practice" });
        audiences.Adding(new Room() { ID = 12, Number = 102, Lesson = "History", Type = "lecture" });

        planner.Adding(new Plan() { Day = "Monday", GroupID = 1, AudienceID = 1, SubjectID = 4 });
        planner.Adding(new Plan() { Day = "Monday", GroupID = 1, AudienceID = 4, SubjectID = 2 });
        planner.Adding(new Plan() { Day = "Monday", GroupID = 1, AudienceID = 2, SubjectID = 8 });
        planner.Adding(new Plan() { Day = "Tuesday", GroupID = 1, AudienceID = 2, SubjectID = 8 });
        planner.Adding(new Plan() { Day = "Tuesday", GroupID = 1, AudienceID = 1, SubjectID = 1 });
        planner.Adding(new Plan() { Day = "Tuesday", GroupID = 1, AudienceID = 5, SubjectID = 5 });
        planner.Adding(new Plan() { Day = "Wendnesday", GroupID = 1, AudienceID = 10, SubjectID = 13 });
        planner.Adding(new Plan() { Day = "Wednesday", GroupID = 1, AudienceID = 9, SubjectID = 9 });
        planner.Adding(new Plan() { Day = "Thursday", GroupID = 1, AudienceID = 7, SubjectID = 10 });
        planner.Adding(new Plan() { Day = "Thursday", GroupID = 1, AudienceID = 3, SubjectID = 11 });
        planner.Adding(new Plan() { Day = "Friday", GroupID = 1, AudienceID = 12, SubjectID = 14 });
        planner.Adding(new Plan() { Day = "Friday", GroupID = 1, AudienceID = 11, SubjectID = 15 });

        planner.Adding(new Plan() { Day = "Monday", GroupID = 2, AudienceID = 10, SubjectID = 12 });
        planner.Adding(new Plan() { Day = "Monday", GroupID = 2, AudienceID = 9, SubjectID = 9 });
        planner.Adding(new Plan() { Day = "Monday", GroupID = 2, AudienceID = 2, SubjectID = 8 });
        planner.Adding(new Plan() { Day = "Tuesday", GroupID = 2, AudienceID = 2, SubjectID = 8 });
        planner.Adding(new Plan() { Day = "Tuesday", GroupID = 2, AudienceID = 1, SubjectID = 1 });
        planner.Adding(new Plan() { Day = "Tuesday", GroupID = 2, AudienceID = 5, SubjectID = 5 });
        planner.Adding(new Plan() { Day = "Wednesday", GroupID = 2, AudienceID = 10, SubjectID = 12 });
        planner.Adding(new Plan() { Day = "Wednesday", GroupID = 2, AudienceID = 6, SubjectID = 7 });
        planner.Adding(new Plan() { Day = "Thursday", GroupID = 2, AudienceID = 7, SubjectID = 10 });
        planner.Adding(new Plan() { Day = "Thursday", GroupID = 2, AudienceID = 9, SubjectID = 9 });
        planner.Adding(new Plan() { Day = "Friday", GroupID = 2, AudienceID = 12, SubjectID = 14 });
        planner.Adding(new Plan() { Day = "Friday", GroupID = 2, AudienceID = 4, SubjectID = 2 });
        audiences.Notify += DisplayMessage;
        groups.Notify += DisplayMessage;
        subjects.Notify += DisplayMessage;
        planner.Notify += DisplayMessage;

        string day = null;
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Choose a day");
            Console.WriteLine("Monday - 1, Tuesday - 2, Wednesday - 3, Thursday - 4, Friday - 5, Week - 6, Exit - 10");
            int d = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            if (d == 1)
            {
                day = "Monday";
            }

            if (d == 2)
            {
                day = "Tuesday";
            }

            if (d == 3)
            {
                day = "Wednesday";
            }

            if (d == 4)
            {
                day = "Thursday";
            }

            if (d == 5)
            {
                day = "Friday";
            }

            if (d == 6)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Choose a group");
                var g = groups.FindAll();
                foreach (var i in g)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"ID = {i.ID} {i.Flow} - {i.GroupNum}");
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Enter id");
                var id = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
                {
                    switch (i)
                    {

                        case 1:
                            day = "Monday";
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            day = "Tuesday";
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            day = "Wednesday";
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            day = "Thursday";
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            day = "Friday";
                            break;

                    }
                    planner.Choose(planner, groups, subjects, audiences, day, id);

                }
                break;
            }

            if (d == 10)
            {
                break;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Choose a group");
            var gr = groups.FindAll();
            foreach (var i in gr)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"ID = {i.ID} {i.Flow} - {i.GroupNum}");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Enter id");
            var groupid = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            planner.Choose(planner, groups, subjects, audiences, day, groupid);


        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static void DisplayMessage(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }
}
```

}

```
namespace Library
 {
   interface IRepository<T> where T : class
  {
    IEnumerable<T> FindAll();
    void Adding(T id);
    void Removing(int id);
    T FindByID(int id);
```

}
}

```
 namespace Library
 {
   public class GroupRepository : IRepository<Group>
{
    public delegate void Handler(string message);
    public event Handler Notify;
     List<Group> groups { set; get; }

    GroupRepository()
    {
        groups = new List<Group>();
    }

    GroupRepository(IEnumerable<Group> grooups)
    {
        groups = new List<Group>(grooups);
    }

    public void Adding(Group group)
    {
        groups.Find((x) => x.ID == group.ID);
        if (group.ID < 0)
        {
            throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("Index out of range");
        }
        if (groups.Exists((x) => x.ID == group.ID))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The group with this id has already exists!");
        }
        if (groups.Exists((x) => x.GroupNum == group.GroupNum && groups.Exists((y) => y.Flow == group.Flow)))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The group of the speciality has already exists!");
        }
        groups.Add(group);

    }

    public void Removing(int id)
    {
        var c = groups.Find((x) => x.ID == id);
        if (id < 0 || id == 0)
        {
            throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("Index out of range");
        }
        groups.Remove(c);
        Notify?.Invoke($"Group {c.GroupNum}-{c.Flow} was removed");
    }

    public IEnumerable<Group> FindAll()
    {
        foreach (var gr in groups)
        {
            yield return gr;
        }
    }

    public Group FindByID(int id)
    {
        groups.Find((x) => x.ID == id);
        if (id < 0 || id == 0)
        {
            throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("Index out of range");
        }
        return groups[id - 1];
    }
    public void Update(Group group)
    {
        var ind = groups.FindIndex((x) => x.ID == group.ID);
        if (ind == -1)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Item not exists");
        }
        groups[ind] = group;
        Notify?.Invoke($"Group {group.GroupNum}-{group.Flow} was updated");
    }

}
```

}

Comment: судя по приведенному коду должно было быть `new Library.GroupRepository()`

Comment: всё равно осталась та проблема

Comment: добавь полный текст ошибки и отредактируй пример кода так, чтобы его можно было скопировать и запустить. В текущем виде, указанная ошибка не появляется.

Comment: есть, Library как dll  подключена

Comment: Обрати внимание, что в первой версии вопроса, твой конструктор был публичным.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

у вас конструктор private a должен быть публичный

```
 public  GroupRepository()
    {
        groups = new List<Group>();
    }
```

Comment: понял,спасибо))